# MDriven framework local installation on VS 2022 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2022, mdriven

MDrivenFramework_7.0.0.13867_Nightly_vs2022 and all previous installers did not work.

Error message when trying to run VS 2022 post installing VSIX

[image: Click to see Error]

Comment: Support Team, this issue continues to all the latest downloads.

Comment: Hi, I'm not from the support team, but it seems that you have the MDriven Designer installed too. I fixed similar error by installing designer and vsix with equal build numbers. But as of today I can't find link to any vsix on the MDriven site...